# How to upload pdf generated with fpdi to cloudinary php

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I have the code below and I want to upload generated pdf to cloudinary but stuck.

My current code is like this:

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceFile("https://testwebsite.com/test.pdf");
$page= $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($page);
$output = $pdf->Output('newfile.pdf', 'S');
$uploadedLogoFileUrl = Cloudinary::uploadFile($output)->getSecurePath();
```

The above shows the pdf in browser and when I use `Cloudinary::uploadFile($pdf->Output())->getSecurePath()` only, cloudinary sees it as null byte value.

Comment: Are you using Cloudinary PHP SDK? Since i am not sure if `Cloudinary::uploadFile()` exists in it

Comment: "The above shows the pdf in browser": That's impossible because it is only available as a string in `$output`. Also `$pdf->setSourceFile("https://testwebsite.com/test.pdf");` is questionable. Do not use an URI as the parameter but use a local path instead.

Comment: @Adi yes I'm using Laravel SDK and `Cloudinary::uploadFile()` exists

Comment: @JanSlabon I am looking for how to upload the PDF output to cloudinary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it with the Cloudinary/Uploader

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pdf->setSourceFile("https://testwebsite.com/test.pdf");
$page= $pdf->importPage(1);
$pdf->addPage();
$pdf->useTemplate($page);

$tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'generated_pdf');
$pdf->Output($tempFile, 'F');

try {
    $cloudinaryResponse = Uploader::upload($tempFile, array(
        "resource_type" => "auto",
        "folder" => "pdfs"
    ));

    $pdfUrl = $cloudinaryResponse['secure_url'];

    echo "PDF uploaded successfully. PDF URL: " . $pdfUrl;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Error uploading PDF: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Just make sure you have the correct path to the FPDI library and the Cloudinary PHP SDK in your project, and ensure that your Cloudinary credentials and folder settings are correct in the upload function.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I get `Error uploading PDF: Path cannot be empty` error

Comment: Oh it seems like the file path is not being accepted, also doesn't 'S' stand for String `$output = $pdf->Output('newfile.pdf', 'S');` I have updated the code